# How can we execute the client code after completing the update panel postback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I have an issue to show the Loader Image when we click the checkbox and hide the loader after retriving the data .Now the 'divData' will be loaded by the load when ever we check the checkbox.Now my scenario is like this the divData is in updatepanel and async trigger checkbox is associated to it.Now I am Showing the Loader like this

```
function ShowProgress(displayValue) {

            var modal = $("<div id='divLoading'/>");
            modal.addClass("modal");
            modal.css('display', displayValue);
            $('body').append(modal);
            var loading = $(".loading");
            loading.show();
            var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
            var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
            loading.css({ top: top, left: left, display: displayValue });
        }
```

here I am passing the displayValue 'inline' when we click the checkbox.I have written code to hide the loader image as given after binding the data to divData.

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "Unload", "ShowProgress('none');", True)
```

Now the above code is not working to hide the loader.The checkbox control is not in another updatepanel.I've tried all the ways . Can anyone help me to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

iam posting a global solution... this works if any partial postback happens the modal loading popup will appear and as soon as the data is fetched the popup will be closed as expected.

register the BeginHandler and EndHandler events of scriptmanager in the MasterPage like the following.

```
       Sys.Application.add_init(appl_init);
        function appl_init() {
            var pgRegMgr = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
            pgRegMgr.add_beginRequest(BeginHandler);
            pgRegMgr.add_endRequest(EndHandler);
        }
        function BeginHandler(sender, args) {
            ShowProgress('block');
        }
        function EndHandler() {
           ShowProgress('none');
        }
        function ShowProgress(displayValue) {

        var modal = $("<div id='divLoading'/>");
        modal.addClass("modal");
        modal.css('display', displayValue);
        $('body').append(modal);
        var loading = $(".loading");
        loading.show();
        var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
        var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
        loading.css({ top: top, left: left, display: displayValue });
    }
```

Hope this helps..